# Iframe que cargue una vista previa de un documento de office

Tags: javascript, php, api, iframe, office365

Estoy creando un extranet y en el se cargan archivos .doc .xls .ppt y se guardan en el servidor en una carpeta ./carpeta/prueba.doc y en el extranet ya se muestra que esta registrado ese archivo, ahora el asunto es que en un iframe despliegue solo la previsualización del documento, no importa que no pueda modificarlo solo que se vea el 'preview' del documento.

Answer (score 7):

Con este sencillo iframe podremos cargar nuestros documentos para visualizarlos acepta Word, Excel, PowerPoint y otros documentos asociados con Google Docs.

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://upgrade.com.mx/_docs/prueba.doc&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Donde

```
http://upgrade.com.mx/_docs/prueba.doc
```

es la ruta del documento en tu servidor.

Comment: Aquí tienes una demo https://jsfiddle.net/rnrlabs/jdc2jbbz/

Answer (score 4):

Como complemento a  respuesta es posibles además de los documentos MS Office, .doc .xls .ppt :

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.snee.com/xml/xslt/sample.doc&embedded=true" style="width:500px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

También es posible cargar archivos `PDF`:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://fzs.sve-mo.ba/sites/default/files/dokumenti-vijesti/sample.pdf&embedded=true#:0.page.20" width="500" height="500" frameborder="2"></iframe>
```

Como limitante quisiera mencionar que los documentos que están protegidos con password, no es posible inyectarles este dato.

Answer (score 1):

A mi me funcionó agregando otra parte al final de la url para archivos .docx

```js
 <iframe src={`https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=${url}&embedded=true`} />
```

y para archivo .pdf asi

```js
<iframe src={url} type="application/pdf" />
```